# Continuity: Topology by Munkres

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, continuity

I can't seem to convince my self of this equality, assume that $f|U_{\alpha}$ is continuous for each $\alpha$, then if V is open in Y for Y being a topological space then, $f^{-1}(V) \cap U_{\alpha}=(f|U_{\alpha})^{-1}(V)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, if $S\subseteq X$ is any subset and $T\subseteq Y$ is any subset,
$$f^{-1}(T)\cap S=\{x\in X:f(x)\in T\,\text{ and }\,x\in S\}=\{x\in S:f(x)\in T\}=(f|_S)^{-1}(T)$$
This is a pure manipulation of sets and functions, there's no topology involved.

(I assume Munkres is applying this result to show that if $f|_{U_\alpha}$ is continuous for all $U_\alpha$ in some open cover of $X$, then $f$ is continuous.)